# Leap year & No Know Class method for selector 'datetoday'

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, date

I'm trying to write a code where i find out if a year is bissextile but on my first line an error appears: "No Know Class method for selector 'datetoday'"... I Don't know why i'm having this error, cause when i tried to put my code into a button it worked just fine... but i need the code to be on 'viewDidLoad', but there it get's that error...

my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSDate *datetoday = [NSDate datetoday];
NSDateFormatter *formatyears = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatyears setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];

NSString *yearStr = [formatyears stringFromDate:datetoday];
int yearint = [yearStr intValue];
int resto;
resto = yearint % 4;

if (resto == 0) {
    teste.text = @"bissexto";
} else {
    teste.text = @"not bissexto";
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[NSDate date]`? That returns the current date.

Comment: The answer from Anoop is correct for getting the current date and time. However I'd like to say that your calculation of a leap year is over simplistic. I don't know if you already know this but check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725098/leap-year-calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `[NSDate date]` to get the current date instead of  `[NSDate datetoday]`.

Your code :

```
NSDate *datetoday = [NSDate datetoday];
```

Correct code :

```
NSDate *datetoday = [NSDate date];
```

And for leap year : ( as understood by Fabio's comment, as your code in non-English, I didnt understood most of the variable names)

```
if(((yearint %4==0)&&(yearint %100!=0))||(yearint %400==0)){
   NSLog(@"Leap Year");
}
else{
  NSLog(@"Not a Leap Year");
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off using NSCalendar to find if the year is a leap year or not.

Comment: I just want to point out that not every calendar supported by iOS/Mac OS X knows leap years. Hebrew Calendar for example knows a leap month.

Comment: @vikingosegundo and fogmeister : Then what should i do, the OP wanted to find leap year, although he didnt had problem in that, He had some other mistake, I myself corrected the code to find leap year.

Comment: Sure, you gave the appropriate answer. We just wanted to point out that calendarial calculations might be not as trivial as expected.