# boolean operations overloading inside classes in c++ and if statements for dates inside a class

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean, operation, boolean-operations

I'm using this code in my previous question:
[Adding the year implementation in c++ using a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489907/adding-the-year-implementation-in-c-using-a-class)

I want to use an if statement to check for dates in a way that if the day was 31 it gets back to 0 and the month gets incremented by one. I even tried to write another method and use it inside of the + operation but this failed as well because I'm incrementing the day in the return function inside of the operation declaration. As a result, it will need to be incremented before checking for the conditions first ! but what if the number was initially 31? there is no month that has 32 days !

I tried to use it but because of my implementation it didn't work as it should

My other question is that I'm trying to use a Boolean reference check with the operation == as well

This is what I've done so far :

```
bool operator==(const Date&) const;

bool Date::operator==(const Date& date) const
{
    if (day == date.day && monthnum == date.monthnum && year == date.year)
        return true;
    else return false;

}
```

but for some reason when I try to test it in the main by saying for example, date1==date2, it doesn't compile !
am I writing it wrong ?

"no operation == matches these operands"
this is the error I get when I try to compile the code

Comment: What error do you get? Show main please

Comment: I don't think asking 2 separate questions in one post is a good idea. How will you mark answers if 2 separate people answer 2 separate questions correctly?

Comment: "no operation == matches these operands" This is the error I get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use an if statement to check for dates in a way that if the day was 31 it gets back to 0 and the month gets incremented by one.

This is as simple to implement as:

```
if (day == 31) {
    day = 0;
    monthnum++;
}
```

---

> I try to test it in the main by saying for example, date1==date2, it doesn't compile ! am I writing it wrong ?

Yeah well, you are declaring a free function `operator==`, while what you want is a member function. Inside `Date` do:

```
class Date {
public:
    // ...
    bool operator==(const Date&) const;
    // ...
};
```

You can also use a free function, to be honest, but that would require more changes and it generally is the same. Just in case you want to use it here's how:

```
bool operator==(const Date& lhs, const Date& rhs) {
    return (lhs.day == rhs.day && lhs.monthnum == rhs.monthnum && lhs.year == rhs.year);
}
```

(I've removed the redundant `if-else` pair).

---

> The compiler states that "no operation == matches these operands". I simply have this code in my main: cout << date1 == date2;

Yes, you should do this instead:

```
cout << (date1 == date2);
```

otherwise what the compiler reads is this:

```
(cout << date1) == date2;
```

Comment: I think the function that you considered to be free is inside the class, since this is the implementation: `bool Date::operator==(const Date& date) const`

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie, I very much doubt so, considering that he is triggering a compilation error.

Comment: No one knows what he does in main. If the function would have been free, `Date::operator==` would also trigger an error.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie, I guess we will see when the OP replies. I'll happily delete this answer if I guessed wrong.

Comment: I am using the first code in my program and it is not compiling. I've tried the second one and I still have the same problem. The compiler states that "no operation == matches these operands".

I simply have this code in my main: cout << date1 == date2;

Comment: THANK YOU ! I didn't expect that coming.