# How to check whether date is valid

Tags: java, date

I can use only `parseInt` and `if`-`else`-statements and I'm stuck right now. I understood the logic, but I can't control for example february dates and leap years. I wrote some statements about it.

```
boolean leap = false;
if (((year % 4) == 0) && ((year % 100) == 0)
        && ((year % 400) == 0) && ((year % 4000) != 0))
    leap = true;
else
    leap = false;
```

But I can't contact with february. Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of your code? for instance, where are you getting `year` from?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021324/java-code-for-calculating-leap-year

Comment: "leap" will equate to true only on multiples of 400 that are not multiples of 4000, which is not how to calculate for leap year :).

Comment: possible duplicate of [leap year calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725098/leap-year-calculation)

Comment: `return  (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0;`

Comment: What puzzles me is what “But I can't contact with february” might want to tell me…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leap year can be evaluated by:

```
    if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))
    {
        leap = true;
    }
    else if (year % 400 == 0)
    {
        leap = true;
    }
    else
    {
        leap = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify @Matt Jones answer but that's just me.

```
leap = false;
if(((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)){
    leap = true;
}
```

same thing basically but a little less typing :)

Comment: If you want to reduce typing, why are you still repeating the useless `if` statement and all these annoying braces? Just `leap = year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0;` is enough.