# Compute average if satisfies the given condition in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a dataset with many kind of missing values such as 9990, 9999, 9999000, 999999 and many more. But all are greater than 9990. I would like to take average of each 24 values. I am trying with the following command but not getting my desire output.

```
awk '{if ($1 < 9990) sum += $1; count++} NR%24==0{print count ? (sum) :9999;sum=count=0}'ifile
```

For example: I need average of each 3 lines in the following data

```
3
3
4
9999
4
99990
13
3
999999
9999
9991
99954
```

I tried with this, but showing different result:

```
awk '{if ($1 < 9990)sum += $1; count++} NR%3==0{print count ? (sum/count) :9999;sum=count=0}'ifile
```

My desire output is

```
3.33
4     Average of 9999 4 99990 is done with 4/1. Because 9999 and 99990 are undefined values.
8    Average of 13 3 999999 is done with (13+8)/2. Because 999999 is an undefined value, so excluded from the average.
9999  All are undefined values, so denoted as 9999.
```

Comment: Why is the average of 9999, 9991 and 99954 equal to 9999, when in all other cases values larger than 9990 are ignored?

Comment: Your awk scripts are only summing lines greater than 9990. Isn't that backwards from what you want? Also do you need averages of 24 or 3 values? For 24 you don't have enough data in your example data.

Comment: Yes. I modified now. But still not printing the desire results.

Comment: I think we're both pointing out that the question, your attempts and the desired output all seem to tackle different problems - which is it?

Comment: For example, when all three lines in a group of three have values larger than 9990, i.e., the sum equals zero - why is the "average" 9999? Where does that come from?

Comment: I would like to write something "CONSTANT" to make sure that this is an undefined value. I mean all values in that day are undefined..

Comment: @EdMorton: I edited the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$1 < 9990 {
    sum += $1;
    count++;
}
NR % 3 == 0 {
    if (count == 0) {
        print "9999";
    } else {
        print sum / count;
    }
    sum = 0;
    count = 0;
}
```

Your mistake is to increment `count` when the value is "undefined". If you write

```
 {if ($1 < 9990) sum += $1; count++}
```

then the `if` statement ends at the next semicolon, not at the closing bracket.