# Regular Expression for date and time(DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss) in QML

Tags: regex, qt, datetime, qml, qtquick2

In QML2 I didn't find any `Calender` control and I have implemented a control which takes date and time as input and I am using the regular expression for the validation which matches dates including leap year and other validations.

The main problem is space/backspace should also be considered as a valid for example:

> `\s\s/\s\s/\s\s \s\s:\s\s:\s\s`

**Following is the code :**

```
TextField{
    id:textEditDate

    width:parent.width * 0.50
    height:parent.height
    text : "01/01/2017 00:00:00"

    inputMask: "99/99/9999 99:99:99"

    validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /^(((([0\s][1-9\s]|[1\s][0-9\s]|[2\s][0-8\s])[\/]([0\s][1-9\s]|[1\s][012\s]))|((29|30|31)[\/]([0\s][13578\s]|[1\s][02\s]))|((29|30)[\/]([0\s][4,6,9]|11)))[\/]([19\s[2-9\s][0-9\s])\d\d|(^29[\/]02[\/]([19\s]|[2-9\s][0-9\s])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)))\s([0-1\s]?[0-9\s]|2[0-3\s]):([0-5\s][0-9\s]):([0-5\s][0-9\s])$/}

    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
}
```

Now, everything works well except for the year and I am not able to match backspace/space for the year and user is not able to clear the year.

Can you please suggest how to achieve this ? or is there any other method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequence to match the year is:

```
([19\s[2-9\s][0-9\s])\d\d
```

Which looks malformed, as the brackets do not match.

Also, the presence of the two digits (using `\d`) means that the expression will not match white space.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the misplaced braces and I changed expression from `\d\d` to `[\d\s][\d\s]` and I am able to match space/backspace. Regarding the braces in `([19\s[2-9\s][0-9\s])\d\d` , I don't know how it is working.Can you please give some suggestions on this?

Comment: I haven't tried to test it, but it looks like a character class containing `19\s[2-9\s` - that is, the opening bracket is also one of the characters.

Comment: Got it !!! If i remove `[` before `19\s` , expression was not working properly as expected and may be the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

## Answer

### Brief

So I decided to make a really nice regex that actually works on leap years properly! I then added the rest of the logic you required, and voila, a beauty!

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/bnUaF8/2)

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?# Date )
    (?# Day ranges )
    (?<d_day28>0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])
    (?<d_day29>0[1-9]|1\d|2\d)
    (?<d_day30>0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|30)
    (?<d_day31>0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])
    (?# Month specifications )
    (?<d_month28>02)
    (?<d_month29>02)
    (?<d_month30>0[469]|11)
    (?<d_month31>0[13578]|1[02])
    (?# Year specifications )
    (?<d_year>\d+)
    (?<d_yearLeap>(?:\d*?(?:(?:(?!00)[02468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))|[48]00|[48])(?=\D))
    (?# Valid date formats )
    (?<d_format>
      (?&d_day28)\/(?&d_month28)\/(?&d_year)|
      (?&d_day29)\/(?&d_month29)\/(?&d_yearLeap)|
      (?&d_day30)\/(?&d_month30)\/(?&d_year)|
      (?&d_day31)\/(?&d_month31)\/(?&d_year)
    )

  (?# Time )
    (?# Time properties )
    (?<t_period12>(?i)[ap]m|[ap]\.m\.(?-i))
    (?# Hours )
    (?<t_hours12>0\d|1[01])
    (?<t_hours24>[01]\d|2[0-3])
    (?# Minutes )
    (?<t_minutes>[0-5]\d)
    (?# Seconds )
    (?<t_seconds>[0-5]\d)
    (?# Milliseconds )
    (?<t_milliseconds>\d{3})
    (?# Valid time formats )
    (?<t_format>
      (?&t_hours12):(?&t_minutes):(?&t_seconds)(?:\.(?&t_milliseconds))?\ ?(?&t_period12)|
      (?&t_hours24):(?&t_minutes):(?&t_seconds)(?:\.(?&t_milliseconds))?
    )

  (?# Datetime )
    (?<dt_format>(?&d_format)\ (?&t_format))
)
\b(?&dt_format)\b
```

Or in one line...

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ZDifJ1/1)

```
\b(?:(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/(?:02)\/(?:\d+)|(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2\d)\/(?:02)\/(?:(?:\d*?(?:(?:(?!00)[02468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))|[48]00|[48])(?=\D))|(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|30)\/(?:0[469]|11)\/(?:\d+)|(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(?:0[13578]|1[02])\/(?:\d+))\ (?:(?:0\d|1[01]):(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d)(?:\.(?:\d{3}))?\ ?(?:(?i)[ap]m|[ap]\.m\.(?-i))|(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d)(?:\.(?:\d{3}))?)\b
```

---

### Explanation

I'll explain the first version as the second version is simply a slimmed down version of it. Note that the regex can easily be changed to accommodate for more formats (only 1 format with slight variations is accepted, but this is a very customizable regex).

- **d_days28**: Match any number from `01` to `28`
- **d_days29**: Match any number from `01` to `29`
- **d_days30**: Match any number from `01` to `30`
- **d_days31**: Match any number from `01` to `31`
- **d_month28**: Match months that may only have *28* days (February - thus `02`)
- **d_month29**: Match months that may only have *29* days (February - thus `02`)
- **d_month30**: Match months that only have *30* days (April, June, September, November - thus `04, 06, 09, 11`)
- **d_month31**: Match months that only have *31* days (January, March, May, July, August, October, December - thus `01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12`)
- **d_year**: Match any year (must have at least one digit `\d`)
- **d_yearLeap**: I'll break this into multiple segments for better clarity

  - `\d*?`

    - Match any number of digits, but as few as possible
  - Match one of the following

    - `(?:(?:(?!00)[02468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))` - Match one of the following
    - `(?:(?!00)[02468][048]|[13579][26])` - Match one of the following

      - One of `02468`, followed by one of `048`, but not `00`
      - One of `13579`, followed by one of `26`
    - `(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00)` - Match one of the following, followed by `00`

      - One of `02468`, followed by one of `048`
      - One of `13579`, followed by one of `26`
    - `[48]00` - Match `400` or `800`
    - `[48]` - Match `4` or `8`
  - `(?=\D|\b)` - Ensure what follows is either a non-digit character `\D` or word boundary character `\b`
- **d_format**: This points to previous groups in order to ensure months are properly formatted and match the days/month and days/year(leap year) requirements so that we can ensure proper date validation
- **t_period**: This was added in case others needed this for validation purposes

  - Ensures the period is either `am, pm, a.m, p.m` or their respective uppercase versions (including things such as `a.M` where multliple cases are used)
- **t_hours12**: Match any hour from `00` to `11`
- **t_hours24**: Match any hour from `00` to `23`
- **t_minutes**: Match any minutes from `00` to `59`
- **t_seconds**: Match any seconds from `00` to `59`
- **t_milliseconds**: Match any 3 digits (`000` to `999`)
- **t_format**: This points to previous groups in order to ensure time is properly formatted. I've added an additional time setting (as well as an addition including milliseconds and time period for others' use)
- **dt_format**: Datetime format to check against (in your case it's `date time` - separation by a space  character)
- Following the define block is `\b(?&dt_format)\b`, which simply matches the `dt_format` as specified above, ensuring what precedes and supercedes it is a word boundary character (or no character) `\b`

#### Leap year

To further understand the leap year section of the regex...

I am assuming the following:

- All years are **NOT** leap years, unless, the following is true

  - ((Year modulo `4` is `0`) **AND** (year modulo `100` is not `0`)) **OR** (year modulo `400` is `0`)
  - Source: [leap year calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/725111/3600709)
  - Leap years have always existed (at least since year 1) - since I don't want to start assuming and do even more research.

The regex works by ensuring:

1. All leap years that end in `0, 4, 8` are **preceded** by a `0, 2, 4, 6, 8` (all of which result in `0` after modulus -> i.e. `24 % 4 = 0`)
2. All leap years that end in `2, 6` are **preceded** by a `1, 3, 5, 7, 9` (all of which result in `0` after modulus -> i.e. `32 % 4 = 0`)
3. All leap years that end in `00`, **for 1. and 2.**, are negated (`(?!00)` does this)
4. All leap years that end in `00` are **preceded** by **1. and 2.** (exactly the same since `4 * 100 = 400` - nothing needs to be changed except the last two digits)
5. Add the years `400, 800, 4, 8` since they are not satisfied by any of the above conditions

---

---

## Edits

### October 25th, 2017

Thanks to [@sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln) for the input on the leap year's functionality. The regex below performs slightly faster due to changes provided in the [comments of this answer by sln](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46940144/3600709) (on a separate question). Changed `(?:(?!00)[02468][048]|[13579][26])` to `(?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])` in the leap year section.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/bnUaF8/3)

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?# Date )
    (?# Day ranges )
    (?<d_day28>0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])
    (?<d_day29>0[1-9]|1\d|2\d)
    (?<d_day30>0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|30)
    (?<d_day31>0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])
    (?# Month specifications )
    (?<d_month28>02)
    (?<d_month29>02)
    (?<d_month30>0[469]|11)
    (?<d_month31>0[13578]|1[02])
    (?# Year specifications )
    (?<d_year>\d+)
    (?<d_yearLeap>(?:\d*?(?:(?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))|[48]00|[48])(?=\D|\b))
    (?# Valid date formats )
    (?<d_format>
      (?&d_day28)\/(?&d_month28)\/(?&d_year)|
      (?&d_day29)\/(?&d_month29)\/(?&d_yearLeap)|
      (?&d_day30)\/(?&d_month30)\/(?&d_year)|
      (?&d_day31)\/(?&d_month31)\/(?&d_year)
    )

  (?# Time )
    (?# Time properties )
    (?<t_period12>(?i)[ap]m|[ap]\.m\.(?-i))
    (?# Hours )
    (?<t_hours12>0\d|1[01])
    (?<t_hours24>[01]\d|2[0-3])
    (?# Minutes )
    (?<t_minutes>[0-5]\d)
    (?# Seconds )
    (?<t_seconds>[0-5]\d)
    (?# Milliseconds )
    (?<t_milliseconds>\d{3})
    (?# Valid time formats )
    (?<t_format>
      (?&t_hours12):(?&t_minutes):(?&t_seconds)(?:\.(?&t_milliseconds))?\ ?(?&t_period12)|
      (?&t_hours24):(?&t_minutes):(?&t_seconds)(?:\.(?&t_milliseconds))?
    )

  (?# Datetime )
    (?<dt_format>(?&d_format)\ (?&t_format))
)
\b(?&dt_format)\b
```

Comment: A beauty indeed !

Comment: *evil_grin* leapseconds? +1

Answer (score 0):

RegEx to check for valid dates following ISO 8601, SQL standard.

- Has a range from 1000-9999
- Checks for Invalid Dates
- Checks for valid leap year dates
- Format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

```
^([1-9]\d{3}[\-.](0[13578]|1[02])[\-.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) ([01]\d|2[0123]):([012345]\d):([012345]\d))|([1-9]\d{3}[\-.](0[469]|11)[\-.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30) ([01]\d|2[0123]):([012345]\d):([012345]\d))|([1-9]\d{3}[\-.](02)[\-.](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]) ([01]\d|2[0123]):([012345]\d):([012345]\d))|(((([1-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[13579][26])00)))[\-.](02)[\-.]29 ([01]\d|2[0123]):([012345]\d):([012345]\d))$
```

- Date can be easily changed to format: DD/MM/YYY
- Also, replace the "-" separator by "/"