# Regular Expression for date format like 1970-09-29T00:00:00.000+0000

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression for the following date/time format:

```
1970-09-29T00:00:00.000+0000
```

My current regex is:

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}+[0-9]+
```

Comment: Great question, maybe show us where your regex went wrong? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Sindhu Please give this a quick read, particularly the 2nd bullet point under "How to ask" https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: The most important thing to note is: you must express clearly your intent. For what you need a regular expression in this case? What are you trying to find/match in your date string?

Comment: I am currently trying to use [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}+[0-9]+

Comment: Unless you're looking for _VALID_ dates, use the general purpose `\d` like what you have. Except you have to escape the `+` metachar

Comment: `\d+-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+\+\d+`? You had `{4}` coded for the first time chunk, you didn't have a `.` for the dot separator, and `+` wasn't escaped and you were missing the last set of digits

Comment: Your regex requires 4 digits immediately after the `T`; your example has 2. You don't capture the `.` or the `+` (which you need to escape), and it's not anchored at the beginning or end. What exactly are you trying to validate? Do you expect your regex to reject a month or day of `99`? I suggest having the regex just validate that you have decimal digits in the right layout, and use other logic to check the values. Finally, and probably most important, you haven't really asked a question.

Comment: Thanks ctwheels. The regex that you provided resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Might be missing some digits there.
The regex should be  `^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\+\d{4}$`

Comment: Check it. How is it now?

Comment: Why not leave it, I like the `\d+` part.

Comment: I meant my comment on this answer. You can copy my code from the comments under the question and add it to your answer if you'd like. No point in adding two different answers. The amount of issues people will face in the year 10000 kills me haha

Comment: True that. But, leap year, now that .. `(?:1(?:5(?:8[48]|9[26])|[6-9](?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048]))|[2-9](?:[0-9](?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048]))|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))`

Comment: Try the leap year I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414732/3600709) instead. `(?:\d*?(?:(?:(?!00)[02468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))|[48]00|[48])(?=\D)`

Comment: @ctwheels - Not bad! If you change this part `(?:(?!00)[02468][048]|[13579][26])` to this `(?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])` it will run twice as fast.

Comment: My bad, tot twice as fast, about %20 faster. `Regex1:   ^(?:\d*?(?:(?:(?!00)[02468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))|[48]00|[48])$
Completed iterations:   500  /  500     ( x 1 )
Matches found per iteration:   2041
Elapsed Time:    2.75 s,   2753.28 ms,   2753282 µs


Regex2:   ^(?:\d*?(?:(?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))|[48]00|[48])$
Completed iterations:   500  /  500     ( x 1 )
Matches found per iteration:   2041
Elapsed Time:    2.29 s,   2287.64 ms,   2287645 µs`

Answer (score 0):

[0-9]{2} - this is month, right? Shouldn't it look like that: (0[0-9])|(1[0-2]) ??

And again [0-9]{2} for day: ([0-2][0-9])|(3[01])
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}+[0-9]+

I'm not sure about "time" part.

PS
You have to be more specific, because I'm not sure if I understand.

Comment: Well if we're gonna be really specific now, add leap years and prevent day `00` and month `00`