# Regex for d/m/yyyy with leap years

Tags: regex, date

I've created regex like this:

```
(((([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[-]([1-9]|1[0-2]))|((29|30|31)[-]([13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[-]([469]|11)))[-]([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]))|(29[-]2[-](([0-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)))
```

Everything is going fine until those dates:

29-2-2017 (it matches 9-2-2017)

31-11-2017 (it matches 1-11-2017)

They don't exist or current year is not leap. How can I achieve not to match them as correct?

Working example below:
https://regex101.com/r/mjfoAH/2

**EDIT**

I've managed finally to edit my regex to match format I need. Here it is for next generations:

```
((((\b[1-9]\b|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[-]([1-9]|1[0-2]))|((29|30|31)[-]([13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[-]([469]|11)))[-]([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]))|(29[-]2[-](([0-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)))
```

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/mjfoAH/3

P.S. About possible duplicate - posted topic is about regex for another date format. Also answer checked there as correct doesn't care about leap years. That's why I created this topic.

Comment: Use the date feature of the programming language you're using to verify a date

Comment: [Use anchors?](https://regex101.com/r/Is7Iid/1)

Comment: @baao - I can't in this case. I need to create regular expression for standard asp .net validator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match valid dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates) - look at the second answer.

Comment: See [my answer to a date question a couple months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414732/3600709). The regex is configurable to your needs (you can create your own date or datetime format from the regex) and it does valid leap years. Note the edited section of my question performs slightly faster than the original answer

Comment: @ctwheels - Indeed it's quite good, but I need it written in one line specifically for my needs.

Comment: @Ashiv3r you can convert it into a one-liner. See the second chunk of code on that answer, it's the one-liner version of the regex above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SAME INFO INSIDE EDIT SECTION IN FIRST POST**

I've managed finally to edit my regex to match format I need. Here it is for next generations:

```
((((\b[1-9]\b|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[-]([1-9]|1[0-2]))|((29|30|31)[-]([13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[-]([469]|11)))[-]([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]))|(29[-]2[-](([0-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)))
```

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/mjfoAH/3

Answer (score 1):

### Brief

As per my comment, I've written an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414732/3600709) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409193/regular-expression-for-date-and-timedd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-in-qml/46414732#46414732) that deals with dates and leap years. The regex is configurable to your needs. Below I've made those tweaks to create a regular expression that will work for your format.

---

### Code

#### Regex (with definition construct)

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/t16F6t/1)

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?# Date )
    (?# Day ranges )
    (?<d_day28>0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]|[1-9])
    (?<d_day29>0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|[1-9])
    (?<d_day30>0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|30|[1-9])
    (?<d_day31>0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01]|[1-9])
    (?# Month specifications )
    (?<d_month28>0?2)
    (?<d_month29>0?2)
    (?<d_month30>0?[469]|11)
    (?<d_month31>0?[13578]|1[02])
    (?# Year specifications )
    (?<d_year>\d+)
    (?<d_yearLeap>(?:\d*?(?:(?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))|[48]00|[48])(?=\D|\b))
    (?# Valid date formats )
    (?<d_format>
      (?&d_day28)-(?&d_month28)-(?&d_year)|
      (?&d_day29)-(?&d_month29)-(?&d_yearLeap)|
      (?&d_day30)-(?&d_month30)-(?&d_year)|
      (?&d_day31)-(?&d_month31)-(?&d_year)
    )
)
\b(?&d_format)\b
```

#### Regex (without definition construct/one-liner)

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/t16F6t/2)

```
\b(?:(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]|[1-9])-(?:0?2)-(?:\d+)|(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|[1-9])-(?:0?2)-(?:(?:\d*?(?:(?:0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))|[48]00|[48])(?=\D|\b))|(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|30|[1-9])-(?:0?[469]|11)-(?:\d+)|(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01]|[1-9])-(?:0?[13578]|1[02])-(?:\d+))\b
```

---

### Explanation

Below I've copied the explanation from the linked post (my answer on another question). The explanation is pretty much the same (minus the time properties)

> I'll explain the first version as the second version is simply a
>   slimmed down version of it. Note that the regex can easily be changed
>   to accommodate for more formats (only 1 format with slight variations
>   is accepted, but this is a very customizable regex).
>
> - **d_days28**: Match any number from `01` to `28`
> - **d_days29**: Match any number from `01` to `29`
> - **d_days30**: Match any number from `01` to `30`
> - **d_days31**: Match any number from `01` to `31`
> - **d_month28**: Match months that may only have *28* days (February - thus `02`)
> - **d_month29**: Match months that may only have *29* days (February - thus `02`)
> - **d_month30**: Match months that only have *30* days (April, June, September, November - thus `04, 06, 09, 11`)
> - **d_month31**: Match months that only have *31* days (January, March, May, July, August, October, December - thus `01, 03, 05, 07,
>     08, 10, 12`)
> - **d_year**: Match any year (must have at least one digit `\d`)
> - **d_yearLeap**: I'll break this into multiple segments for better clarity
>
>   - `\d*?`
>
>     - Match any number of digits, but as few as possible
>   - Match one of the following
>
>     - `(?:(?:(?!00)[02468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00))`
>   - Match one of the following
>
>     - `(?:(?!00)[02468][048]|[13579][26])` - Match one of the following
>
>       - One of `02468`, followed by one of `048`, but not `00`
>       - One of `13579`, followed by one of `26`
>     - `(?:(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])00)` - Match one of the following, followed by `00`
>
>       - One of `02468`, followed by one of `048`
>       - One of `13579`, followed by one of `26`
>     - `[48]00` - Match `400` or `800`
>     - `[48]` - Match `4` or `8`
>   - `(?=\D|\b)` - Ensure what follows is either a non-digit character `\D` or word boundary character `\b`
> - **d_format**: This points to previous groups in order to ensure months are properly formatted and match the days/month and
>     days/year(leap year) requirements so that we can ensure proper date
>     validation
> - **t_period**: This was added in case others needed this for validation purposes
>
>   - Ensures the period is either `am, pm, a.m, p.m` or their respective uppercase versions (including things such as `a.M` where
>       multliple cases are used)
> - **t_hours12**: Match any hour from `00` to `11`
> - **t_hours24**: Match any hour from `00` to `23`
> - **t_minutes**: Match any minutes from `00` to `59`
> - **t_seconds**: Match any seconds from `00` to `59`
> - **t_milliseconds**: Match any 3 digits (`000` to `999`)
> - **t_format**: This points to previous groups in order to ensure time is properly formatted. I've added an additional time setting (as
>     well as an addition including milliseconds and time period for others'
>     use)
> - **dt_format**: Datetime format to check against (in your case it's `date time` - separation by a space  character)
> - Following the define block is `\b(?&dt_format)\b`, which simply matches the `dt_format` as specified above, ensuring what precedes and
>     supercedes it is a word boundary character (or no character) `\b`
>
> #### Leap year
>
> To further understand the leap year section of the regex...
>
> I am assuming the following:
>
> - All years are **NOT** leap years, unless, the following is true
>
>   - ((Year modulo `4` is `0`) **AND** (year modulo `100` is not `0`)) **OR** (year modulo `400` is `0`)
>   - Source: [leap year calculation](https://regex101.com/r/t16F6t/1)
>   - Leap years have always existed (at least since year 1) - since I don't want to start assuming and do even more research.
>
> The regex works by ensuring:
>
> 1. All leap years that end in `0, 4, 8` are **preceded** by a `0, 2, 4, 6, 8` (all of which result in `0` after modulus -> i.e. `24 % 4 =
>      0`)
> 2. All leap years that end in `2, 6` are **preceded* by a `1, 3, 5, 7, 9` (all of which result in `0` after modulus -> i.e. `32 % 4 = 0`)
> 3. All leap years that end in `00`, **for 1. and 2.**, are negated (`(?!00)` does this)
> 4. All leap years that end in `00` are **preceded** by **1. and 2.** (exactly the same since `4 * 100 = 400` - nothing needs to be changed
>      except the last two digits)
> 5. Add the years `400, 800, 4, 8` since they are not satisfied by any of the above conditions

Comment: Almost got it, but the format I need suppose to valid only d/M/yyyy, but is allows dd/MM/yyyy too :)

Comment: So you don't need to match dates that are preceded by `0`? So instead of matching `01-01-2017`, you want to match `1-1-2017`?

Comment: Yes, it's only for certain culture info. I've already got regex for dd/mm/yyyy done :)

Comment: In that case see [this](https://regex101.com/r/bnUaF8/4) regex, it no longer matches preceding `0`. Why wouldn't you just use the same regex for both cases though?

Comment: Almost, it doesn't match 31-12-2017 which is correct... And I need to create different regex'es for different culture infos :)

Comment: I've added an answer for my problem in edit section.