# Could you explain what is happening in this code?

Tags: c, leap-year

Please explain what is happening in the code.

I tried the if else that did not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isLeapYear(int year)
{
   return ((!(year % 4) && year % 100) || !(year % 400));
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Please give a complete example of how it doesn't work.

Comment: There is no *if else* in the code you've posted, and the leap year algorithm is well known and documented. Any semi-functional internet search engine should be able to find a result for *leap year calculation* - in fact, a very basic search of this site for [leap year calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/725098/62576) works.

Answer (score 1):

Method to check whether the given year is leap year or not is

> 1. If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2. Otherwise, go to step 5.
> 2. If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3. Otherwise, go to step 4.
> 3. If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go to step 4. Otherwise, go to step 5.
> 4. The year is a leap year.
> 5. The year is not a leap year.

Now Apply your `if` condition to above steps.

```
((!(year % 4) && year % 100) || !(year % 400))

1. !(year % 4)  --> is step1 
2. year % 100   --> is step2 
3. !(year % 400) --> is step3
```