# Select all records if it is a leap year else exclude 29 february

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to exclude people with birthdays on 29.02 this year, because this year is not a leap year and the following query is working. But when I set the year to 2024, it is not giving me any results. I want to select all records if a year is leap and have a where clause if a year is not.

How can I have if clause in where statement?

```
DECLARE @year int
set @year = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
--set @year = 2024

SELECT * FROM Person
WHERE ISDATE(CAST(@YEAR AS char(4)) + '0229') != 1 AND MONTH(DateOfBirth) != 2 AND DAY(DateOfBirth)!= 29
```

Comment: Don't use IF in a WHERE clause. Stick to regular AND/OR, and everything will be fine.

Comment: How do you know if a year is a leap year?

Comment: People who have a birthday on 29/02 still have birthdays in non-leap years, so excluding them seems "wrong".

Comment: @jarlh - `ISDATE('20240229')` returns `1` and `ISDATE('20230229')` returns `0`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725098/leap-year-calculation gives you the formula to include in your where clause.  every 4 years except when it's divisible by 100 unless it's divisible by 400.  so year 4,8,12... but not 100, but include 400.  so case when .... then include 2/29. else don't.

Comment: @Larnu I will have different logic for them

Comment: The statement "*Exclude (is not a leap year AND birthdate is Feb 29)*" is equivalent to "*Include (is a leap year OR birthdate is not Feb 29)*", which is equivalent to "*Include (is a leap year OR birth month is not Feb OR birth day-of-month is not 29)*", which translates to `WHERE (ISDATE(CAST(@YEAR AS char(4)) + '0229') = 1 OR MONTH(DateOfBirth) != 2 OR DAY(DateOfBirth) != 29)`.

Comment: What is it you are *actually* trying to do here, work out what someone's birthday would be this year?

Comment: Thank you @TN. Your solution is working. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @Larnu I am displaying on the frontend list of users that have birthdays today, tomorrow and upcoming next week and I came into an error that 29 feb cannot be included because this date doesn't exist on a non-leap-year, so for a non-leap-year I will have one more list where I will display the birthdays on that date in order to let the users wish their birthdays. I decided to create it as a separate query

Comment: Why not work out what their birthday would be this year, and then if it's in the next -1 to +7 days?

Comment: I tried this but I am getting *Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid* because of this line ***datepart(dayofyear, Person.DateOfBirth)-datepart(dayofyear, getdate()) NumberOfDays, DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(DateOfBirth), DAY(DateOfBirth))) AS Datediff***

Comment: `I will have different logic for them` -> if this is not "on a leap year we'll use Feb 28th" are you sure all of your users will be happy with your logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "*Exclude (is not a leap year AND birthdate is Feb 29)*" is equivalent to "*Include (is a leap year OR birthdate is not Feb 29)*", which is equivalent to "*Include (is a leap year OR birth month is not Feb OR birth day-of-month is not 29)*", which translates to:

```
-- Only include Feb 29 birthdates if a leap year
WHERE (ISDATE(CAST(@YEAR AS char(4)) + '0229') = 1
       OR MONTH(DateOfBirth) != 2
       OR DAY(DateOfBirth) != 29)
```

This might actually be more readable with the "not" factored back out.

```
-- If not a leap year, exclude Feb 29 birthdates
WHERE NOT (ISDATE(CAST(@YEAR AS char(4)) + '0229') = 0
           AND MONTH(DateOfBirth) = 2
           AND DAY(DateOfBirth) = 29)
```

Per Larnu's comment, you might want to consider alternate handling of the non-lead-year Feb 29 case - Perhaps wish them a happy birthday on Feb 28 or March 1.

Comment: should one subtract 1 if their birthday is on feb29th on a non-leap year or add one? so it becomes a valid date? ahh leap day birthdays...

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering the X of what I feel is an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) here; the OP doesn't need logic to **exclude** people with a birthday of 29 February, they need a way to work out what their birthday is for a specific (this) year, regardless of if it's a leap year.

This can be quite simple; just add the number of years that have passed since their birthday. SQL Server will automatically handle leap years, so `2004-02-29` plus 19 years would result in `2023-02-28`.

So, if you want people who have a birthday in the next week:

```sql
WITH Birthdays AS(
    SELECT BD.BirthDate,
           DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(BD.BirthDate),BD.BirthDate) AS BirthDay --This year's birthday
    FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'19840405')),
                (CONVERT(date,'19961031')),
                (CONVERT(date,'20040229')))BD(BirthDate))
SELECT *
FROM Birthdays
WHERE BirthDay >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
  AND BirthDay < CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()));
```

Note that different countries do have different rules on when someone ages. In the UK (which is where I live) they aren't actually classed as *legally* aging until 01 March, however, in other countries it's 28 February. If you wanted it to be 01 March, then you could use an additional CTE to check if the `DAY` of the 2 dates is the same; if it isn't then add a day to the `BirthDay` to make it 01 March (rather than 28 February):

```sql
WITH Birthdays AS(
    SELECT BD.BirthDate,
           DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(BD.BirthDate),BD.BirthDate) AS BirthDay --This year's birthday
    FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'19840405')),
                (CONVERT(date,'19961031')),
                (CONVERT(date,'20040229')))BD(BirthDate)),
AdjustedBirthdays AS(
    SELECT BirthDate,
           CASE DAY(Birthdate) WHEN DAY(Birthday) THEN Birthday ELSE DATEADD(DAY,1,Birthday) END AS BirthDay
    FROM Birthdays)
SELECT *
FROM AdjustedBirthdays
WHERE BirthDay >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
  AND BirthDay < CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()));
```